# Alternative to dp for text view alignment with background

Tags: java, android

I have a text view on my android app which I want to place in a specific place on the screen.  This is because there is a background on the screen and the text view has to show in line with the space I have made for it in the background.

I'm moving the text around using the margins and entering for example 20dp for top margin 10dp for right margin.

Is there any other method I can use in order to ensure that the text view will be displayed in the right place on all devices?  As other dvices mas have a higher or lower res.

Comment: That's the point of dp (dip). A dip, or a device-independent pixel is a uniform size across devices.

Comment: "This is because there is a background on the screen and the text view has to show in line with the space I have made for it in the background." -- this is a bug, IMHO.

Comment: I don't believe so, the background is a png you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use relativelayout and you can control the position of a view in a much better way.

`android:layoutalign_parentright=true` tag makes the view to be the right always.

`android:align_right="@id/someViewId"` makes the right edge of this view aligned with the right edge of **someViewId** view.

It packs a lot of tags that enables you to do such stuff.